# React native image upload with fetch Post but facing issue?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am having an issue with uploading an image from my camera roll or to my API. here is the code that I am currently using. I am able to get the image data from both the camera roll and camera. I just am having an issue of posting the data to the server. I don't know where is the issue. But i thought there is a problem in my formData()

Also in advanced i check my api it's working if i upload the image from postman or advanced rest client then it's perfectly working. Dont know why it's not working with react native.

Version i am using

"react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
"react-native": "0.49.5",
"react-native-camera-kit": "^5.3.14"

My code for submitting the photo to server

onFormSubmit = (e) => {

```
var photo = {
  uri: this.state.uri[0].uri, == image path file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1511787860629.jpg
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  name: 'photo.jpg',
  size: this.state.uri[0].size,==> size of image
};
var form = new FormData();
form.append("imageLink", photo);

const config = {
 method: 'POST',
 headers: {
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
 },
 body: form,
}

fetch("http://localhost:port/api/User/imageUpload", config)
 .then((responseData) => {
     // Log the response form the server
     // Here we get what we sent to Postman back
     console.log(responseData);
 })
 .catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
 })
```

}

And api return me this error ==> {"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Invalid content-type header: multipart missing boundary"}

Comment: Also i tried with xhr and axios with content type undefined but none is working for me

Comment: Do not specify `Content-Type` at all.

Comment: Even if i not specify the Content-type then i got different issue but no success. {"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"path is not allowed. bytes is not allowed"}

Comment: @10101010 This is my curl request without header  [link] (https://pastebin.com/S72QBs2g)

Comment: Things work differently I guess.

Comment: @10101010 Will you plz check what i am doing wrong, my backend based on hapijs. I tried several option to hit api like without header, But this is not working

Comment: You need to debug this from the backend, to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Same error here. The situation is exactly the same. any news?

Comment: seems the issue is with file path

Answer (score -3):

Try to change your localhost address with the computer IP and check if it works.